# Java: How to speed up a timer upon a mouse click

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouseevent

I have to create a countdown timer which speeds up when the mouse is clicked.

I have tried a lot, and basically I do not know how to implement the `MouseListener` in the code. My code looks a bit like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;



public class CountDown{
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input time in secs => : ");
        String sec = sc.nextLine();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        timer = new Timer();
        interval = Integer.parseInt(sec);
        System.out.println(sec);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(setInterval());    
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private static final int setInterval() {
        int x = 1;
        if (interval == x)
            timer.cancel();
        return --interval;
        MouseEvent e = new MouseEvent();
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
             x = x*2;
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a MouseListener, you need to have something for it to listen to -- usually this means creating a GUI. Where's your GUI code? If a Swing GUI, then use a Swing Timer (`javax.swing.Timer`), not a `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: time will significantly increase if you double the timer.

Comment: Not sure how you intend to get the mouse to work with a console/terminal program...

Comment: A GUI needs not to be made at this time, everything should be done in the console. Making the GUI is the next assingment I think.

Comment: OK, well then good luck with this program.

Comment: @WesleyBrants Sorry, you don't get `java.awt.event.MouseEvent` (or `MouseListener`) without  a GUI.

Comment: Consider contacting your instructor or classmates for clarification on your assignment requirements, because something is way off here.

Comment: Is it then possible to press a key on the keyboard to do the same or is the GUI really something I need to do?

Comment: @WesleyBrants 18 lines of code to make a basic Swing GUI. [Reference](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). (19 if you want to make it behave "correctly" on close).

Comment: *"Is it then possible to press a key on the keyboard to do the same or is the GUI really something I need to do?"* - No (strictly speaking), you will only know when the user presses the [Enter] key, then you'll be able to react

Comment: Based on your current code, when required, cancel the current stoner and schedule a new one